# How to restrict transactions of token directly on metamask

Tags: solidity, erc-20, metamask

What I am trying to build here is an application that restricts the usage of metamask to transfer my erc20 token. I want owner to send it to a group1, where group1 cannot share it with anyone but group2. group2 cannot send the token to anyone at all. This can be implemented on solidity code, but my progress here is questionable as anyone can transfer the token from metamask directly.

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to tell if transaction originated from metamask. Locking the tokens once it reached some address on smart contract would be a better approach.

Or maybe disable the transaction function called by metamask, then not only the metamask none of wallets would be able to transfer the token. That would go against ERC standards.